# jQuery: slideUp() delay() then slideDown; not working

Tags: jquery, delay, slideup, slidedown

I'm trying to implement a very simple footer notification element to slide up for a moment, then slide back down. I'm using:

```
$('button').click( function () {
    $('#message-box').slideUp('slow').delay(1500).slideDown('slow');
});
```

However, when you click the button, it delays for the 1500 ms then slides up and never slides down.

http://jsfiddle.net/jrMH3/17/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you actually want is this:

```
 $('#message-box').slideDown('slow').delay(1500).slideUp('slow');
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JDfae/).  Though it seems a bit backwards given your layout, [`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) is for *showing* an element, and [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) is for *hiding* an element...even though given your CSS it's actually going up when shown.

Also as an aside, you don't need `<html>` and `<body>` tags when editing the fiddle, these are already included...any content in the html frame will go inside the `<body>`.

Comment: Doh, completely failed to notice that quirk, silly :) Thanks Nick!