# jquery $.slideUp() works well, but $.slideDown() doesn't work at all

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown, slideup

Guys I've seen [jQuery: slideUp() delay() then slideDown; not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833076/jquery-slideup-delay-then-slidedown-not-working), I exactly coded:

`$('.flash_message').slideDown(800).delay(5000).slideUp(1000);`

but the slideDown doesn't seem to work.

In other words:

``$('.flash_message').slideDown(800).delay(5000).slideUp(1000);`

and

`$('.flash_message').delay(5000).slideUp(1000);`

are producing the same result!

---

PHP code that generates `.flash_message` element: (I use codeigniter)

```
if ($this->session->flashdata('message_array'))
{
    foreach($this->session->flashdata('message_array') as $message)
    {
        echo "<div class='flash_message {$message[0]}'>{$message[1]}</div>";
    }
}
```

---

Sample HTML generated:

```
<div class="flash_message success">Event added successfully.</div>
```

---

Updated: I GOT THE PROBLEM:

**slideDown doesn't work at all**

`$('.flash_message').slideDown(800);`

doesn't do anything!

Comment: What kind of html element is .flash_message? (maybe a good idea to post the HTML too)

Comment: Thank you. I don't believe but it might be important. At least if you know what is happened, may make you more sure about the its content.

Comment: What do you mean by "producing the same result"? The last example isn't producing anything since you first delay and then hide. The first example shows the div first and the hides it.

Comment: @Niklas No Niklas, By "producing the result" I mean generating HTML. In the example above: `<div class="flash_message success">Event added successfully.</div>`

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce the error here? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment. I don't delete it for others to not be confused. That I said "are producing the same result", I mean that the code `$('.flash_message').slideDown(800).delay(5000).slideUp(1000);` and `$('.flash_message').delay(5000).slideUp(1000);` do not differ at all. They give the same result. The function "`.slideDown`" doesn't do anything. It doesn't differ whether to put it in the code or put it not. Sorry for my terrible english

Comment: And the problem is exactly that. As I updated my question, it looks that `$('.flash_message').slideDown(800);` doesn't work at all.

Comment: Is your code in a document ready function? Such as: `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`

Comment: @MikeLentini Yes; here it is: `$(document).ready(function(){/*$('.flash_message').slideDown(800, function() { $(this).delay(500).slideUp(1000); })*/ $('.flash_message').slideDown(1000); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the delay and the slideUp into the callback of the initial slideDown function

Code in the callback will be executed once the slideDown has finished.

Heres a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FK2Fd/1/

```
$(function(){

    $('.flash_message').slideDown(800, function(){
       $(this).delay(500).slideUp(1000); 
    });

});
```

Comment: So why does http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JDfae/ works with code: `$('#message-box').slideDown('slow').delay(1500).slideUp('slow');` ?

Comment: I don't know why, but I've seen that the problem with my own Firefox! Though I use the latest version (in ubuntu). Thanks any way. I accept your answer anyway.